# How to make a simple pattern detector in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have some code: `list=["r","s","r","s"]`
I would want to print the next digit of the code. The expected output would, of course, be "r". Is there any way to do this in python?

I tried a couple of programs online, but they all didn't help me.

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with Python coding.  Can you solve this problem with pencil and paper?

Comment: well, depends what you want to achieve

Comment: Maybe you can use ml for this, X will be index and y will be letters 

Comment: If it's for an important script that is used a lot, pencil and paper can't really magically work by themselves so... Just write a program.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your pattern starts at the beginning of your array, here is a way to find the next element:

```
def repeat(pattern, length):
    return (length//len(pattern))*pattern + pattern[:length%len(pattern)]
    
def find_pattern(array):
    # we successively try longer and longer patterns, starting with length 1
    for len_attempt, _ in enumerate(array, 1):
        pattern = array[:len_attempt]
        if repeat(pattern, len(array)) == array:
            return repeat(pattern, len(array)+1)[-1]
```

Here is the output of this function for various patterns:

```
arr = ['r', 's', 'r', 's']
print(find_pattern(arr))
>>> r
arr = ['r', 's', 'w', 'r', 's']
print(find_pattern(arr))
>>> w
arr = ['r', 's', 'w', 'w', 's']
print(find_pattern(arr))
>>> r  # considering a pattern of length 5
```

**Explanation:**

First of all, we define a `repeat` function which will be useful later. It repeats a pattern to a given length. For example, if we give `['r', 's']` as a pattern and a length of 5, it will return `['r', 's', 'r', 's', 'r']`.

Then, we try patterns of length 1, 2, 3... until when the repeat of this pattern gives us the original array. At this point we know that this pattern works best, and we return the next predicted element. In the worst case scenario, the program will consider a pattern of length `len(array)` in which case it will just return the first element of this array.

You can easily tweak this program to give :

- not only the next element of the array, but the nth one.
- The length of the pattern

If the pattern doesn't necessarily start at the beginning of your array, it shouldn't be too difficult to make this program work for this case too. (hint: remove the n first elements of the array and find a pattern that ends with these elements.)

I hope this is what you are looking for!